# How to preview and test the order received page?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to test how the order received page template looks in woocommerce. The template says `Thank you. Your order has been received.` and underneath is current order information.  How do i view this template without making a payment?

I've found **order-details.php** in **woocommerce/my-account** and i've found **thankyou.php** in **woocommerce/checkout** but how do i preview the `order recieved` page so i can see what the customer sees after they make a purchase?

Comment: Create a dummy order. You can use stripe/paypal tesing... or you can accept check/bacs payments and mark your dummy payment as processing. Then you can visit that page with the ID generated by your dummy order.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a 100% discount coupon then place the order.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$order->get_checkout_order_received_url()`

This will add a button in the WooCommerce admin order edit pages:

```php
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details( $order ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $order->get_checkout_order_received_url() . '" target="_blank" class="button" style="margin-top:10px">' . __( 'My text', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 10, 1 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

also an option -

use https://sandbox.authorize.net/

Create an account there. (it's free)
Then go to the "ACCOUNT" menu option, then find > "API Credentials & Keys" (the link is somewhere on that page under Security settings) 
Generate a New "Transaction Key".
For secret Question:    What is your pet's name? use "Simon"  (its hard coded for SB)

Use the API Login ID and New "Transaction Key"  in you sites woocoommerce settings > checkout Authorize.New Cards settings.
Be sure to check Authorize.Net sandbox [] Enable Authorize.Net sandbox (Live Mode if Unchecked), and any other desired settings (Accepted cards)

I used my real card to test a purchase and all worked fine in staging. I don't think transactions get passed to the cc company.  But if you are worried, then you an find and void the transactions -
in https://sandbox.authorize.net,  click Unsettled Transactions, find your test, then void it.  That worked ok in testing anyway - BTW, I did have some issues  using the "test" credit card numbers available (like visa 4222222222222) - that's why I used my real card for final testing.